# Создание цепочки предикатов для фильтра в стриме

Tags: java, rest, потоки-данных, параметры, фильтр

Есть REST сервис. В GET запросе могут присутствовать параметры: обычные на сравнение, дата "от", дата "до". Параметры могут быть в любой комбинации.
Параметры даты формируют временной промежуток:

- если нет даты "от" - то отбираются от самой первой (по времени) записи
- если нет "до" - до самой то отбираются до самой последней (по времени) записи

Идея в том, чтобы создать фильтр для любой ситуации и использовать его в stream()

Есть такая реализация:

```
  private Specification<User> byFilter(Map<String, String> requestParams) {
    return requestParams
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(param -> !param.getKey().equals(TIME_FROM) && !param.getKey().equals(TIME_TO))
            .map(entry -> byAttributeValue(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .reduce(Specification::and).orElse(null);
  }
```

Репозиторий:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

  List<User> findAllByOrderByTimeAsc();

  static Specification<User> byAttributeValue(String field, Object value) {
    return (user, query, cb) -> cb.equal(user.get(field), value);
  }

  Set<User> findByTimeBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);

}
```

Смысл таков: если есть хоть один параметр по времени, то идет выборка по дате (много кода со связями, не представлено) потом выборка с использованием byFilter(), потом выборки сводятся; если нет - сразу выборка через byFilter().

Работает, но реализация не нравится. Кажется избыточной, не гибкой. Не получается додумать использование Specification, Predicate в stream().

**Как в byFilter "прикрутить" фильтр по дате?**

**Будет здорово, если кто-нибудь даст толковое объяснение принципа работы кода**

```
static Specification<User> byAttributeValue(String field, Object value) {
        return (user, query, cb) -> cb.equal(user.get(field), value);
      }
```

Comment: Если хотите правильно - делайте свой запрос к БД с фильтрами, а выбирать все из базы и фильтровать в коде - это плохая практика.

Comment: Таким подходом как раз и формируется запрос к БД *userRepository.findAll(byFilter(requestParams))*